# Concat multiple arraylist and put in tree map

Tags: java, loops, concatenation, treemap

Below is the code i am facing problem with.
I have a List attribute list which gets data on every iteration (m=0,m=1 etc)
Every time data is different. 
What i want to do is that I should somehow concatenate data on these iterations. So that whole can be put into treemap. 
DRY RUN

## Because what is happening is at m=0,I get a value(which satisfies my if loop) , I put it in tree map, it gets checked in if, value gets set.

## But now when second iteration happens it goes to else and that already set value gets updated to null .

//So, I want to concatenate all values coming in m=0,m=1. Such that value when set doesn't change to null.

try {
            for (int i = 0; i < Data.size(); i++) {

```
        if(Data.get(i).getData().size()>0){

                for (int m = 0; m < Data.get(i).getData().size(); m++) {

            try{    

                List<Entry>attributeList=Data.get(i).getData().get(m).getAnotherListofdata().getEntry();

                if(attributeList.size()>0){

                    TreeMap <String,String> attributeMap = new TreeMap<String,String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);

                    for(int j=0; j<attributeList.size();j++){


                        attributeMap.put(attributeList.get(j).getName(), attributeList.get(j).getValue());


                    }
                    if (attributeMap.containsKey("somekey")){

                    //code
                    }else {

                    //code

                    }
```

}

Comment: Please format you code and question properly

Answer (score 1):

Declare  TreeMap  attributeMap outside of for loop as you are initializing it again and hence won't be able to concatenate.

Comment: By "initializing it again", you mean "initializing on each loop iteration"?

Answer (score 0):

Your objective is TreeMap should hold both values for a given key?
If yes, change your Map symantic as

Map < Key,List < Value > >

That said when the key is available you instead of directly setting it, get the value collection and add the value to it.

If you have some other objective please clarify.